# Kivy + Python повесить формулу на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

есть вот такой интерфейс

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        al = AnchorLayout()
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=[.5, .2])

        bl.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl.add_widget(Button(text='получить'))

        al.add_widget(bl)
        return al

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как при нажатии кнопки выводить ниже число из инпута возведенный в квадрат?

Comment: в чём у вас сложности: 1- как любое действие по нажатию на кнопку выполнить? 2- как распознать введённую строку как число? 3- как число в квадрат возвести не знаете? 4- как число в строку превратить? 5- Как строку в GUI показать?

Comment: @jfs При нажатии кнопки выводить к примеру в лейбл ниже число из инпута возведенный в квадрат, я не пойму как обратиться к кнопке.
Пробовал создать вторую функцию но не могу обратиться к кнопке

Comment: я указал пять шагов: если у вас сложности по любому из шагов, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос именно об этом шаге (они независимые). Если вы знаете как объединить шаги, то явно покажите ваш код для каждого пункта.

Comment: @jfs такое чувство, что вы избегаете ответа нарочно, я не попросил все делать, а лишь показать пример, как мне реализовать простой вывод из строки по нажатию на кнопку, я просто не знаю как это сделать в данный момент

Comment: вопросы на Stack Overflow не только и не столько для автора вопроса существуют, а чтобы люди потом через поисковик ответы находили. У вас вопрос по сути как сделать A,B,C,D,E (я указал явно шаги). Представьте есть 1000 простых действий: если не знать как отдельные действия выполнять, то 1000 Stack Overflow вопросов достаточно, чтобы ответить на все случаи. Если же отвечать на каждый A,B,C,D,E вопрос по отдельности, то получается не 1000, а уже [`C(1000, 5) = 1000!/(5!*(1000-5)!) = 8250291250200`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) вопросов

Comment: если из 1000 простых задач составлять вопросы по 5 подзадач в каждом, то огромное количество вопросов простейших получается. Я могу ответить на 1000 простых вопросов (посмотрите мою историю, я уже больше чем на 1000 вопросов ответил), но отвечать на все возможные независимые сочетания я считаю нецелесообразным, если нет проблем с объединением отдельных шагов (если есть проблема, то покажите, что вы можете отдельные шаги выполнить). Другие люди, если им не надоело на такие составные вопросы отвечать, могут ответить, я не стал закрывать ваш вопрос.

Comment: [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)